# Can't rebuild VirtualBox kernel modules

Tags: linux, virtualbox, fedora

Some days ago I've upgraded my kernel to the latest version and since then VirtualBox won't work. I get:

```
Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)
```

I've searched and I found that I need to rebuild VirtualBox kernel modules but when I try to run

```
sudo /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup
```

But it fails with:

```
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-setup.log to find out what went wrong.
```

The content of the log file is:

```
Building the main VirtualBox module.
Error building the module:
make V=1 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_ALL= -C /lib/modules/5.8.4-200.fc32.x86_64/build M=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 -j4 modules
make[1]: warning: -jN forced in submake: disabling jobserver mode.
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/vbox.0 \
single-build= \
need-builtin=1 need-modorder=1
  gcc -Wp,-MMD,/tmp/vbox.0/linux/.SUPDrv-linux.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/include -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -fno-PIE -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Wno-format-security -Wno-address-of-packed-member -std=gnu89 -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -fno-jump-tables -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-frame-address -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-format-overflow -Wno-address-of-packed-member -O2 -fno-allow-store-data-races -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -fstack-protector -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wno-unused-const-variable -fno-var-tracking-assignments -g -pg -mrecord-mcount -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -flive-patching=inline-clone -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-stringop-truncation -Wno-zero-length-bounds -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-restrict -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -fno-strict-overflow -fno-merge-all-constants -fmerge-constants -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=designated-init -fmacro-prefix-map=./= -fcf-protection=none -Wno-packed-not-aligned -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-pie -Wno-declaration-after-statement -I./include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_WITHOUT_PRAGMA_ONCE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DSUPDRV_WITH_RELEASE_LOGGER -DVBOX_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_SET_IN_VBOXDRV -DIPRT_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_PRESERVING -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS -DCONFIG_VBOXDRV_AS_MISC -DRT_ARCH_AMD64  -DMODULE  -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"SUPDrv_linux"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"vboxdrv"' -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o /tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c
  gcc -Wp,-MMD,/tmp/vbox.0/.SUPDrv.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/include -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -fno-PIE -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Wno-format-security -Wno-address-of-packed-member -std=gnu89 -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -fno-jump-tables -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-frame-address -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-format-overflow -Wno-address-of-packed-member -O2 -fno-allow-store-data-races -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -fstack-protector -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wno-unused-const-variable -fno-var-tracking-assignments -g -pg -mrecord-mcount -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -flive-patching=inline-clone -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-stringop-truncation -Wno-zero-length-bounds -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-restrict -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -fno-strict-overflow -fno-merge-all-constants -fmerge-constants -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=designated-init -fmacro-prefix-map=./= -fcf-protection=none -Wno-packed-not-aligned -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-pie -Wno-declaration-after-statement -I./include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_WITHOUT_PRAGMA_ONCE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DSUPDRV_WITH_RELEASE_LOGGER -DVBOX_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_SET_IN_VBOXDRV -DIPRT_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_PRESERVING -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS -DCONFIG_VBOXDRV_AS_MISC -DRT_ARCH_AMD64  -DMODULE  -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"SUPDrv"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"vboxdrv"' -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrv.o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrv.c
  gcc -Wp,-MMD,/tmp/vbox.0/.SUPDrvGip.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/include -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -fno-PIE -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Wno-format-security -Wno-address-of-packed-member -std=gnu89 -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -fno-jump-tables -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-frame-address -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-format-overflow -Wno-address-of-packed-member -O2 -fno-allow-store-data-races -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -fstack-protector -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wno-unused-const-variable -fno-var-tracking-assignments -g -pg -mrecord-mcount -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -flive-patching=inline-clone -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-stringop-truncation -Wno-zero-length-bounds -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-restrict -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -fno-strict-overflow -fno-merge-all-constants -fmerge-constants -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=designated-init -fmacro-prefix-map=./= -fcf-protection=none -Wno-packed-not-aligned -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-pie -Wno-declaration-after-statement -I./include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_WITHOUT_PRAGMA_ONCE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DSUPDRV_WITH_RELEASE_LOGGER -DVBOX_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_SET_IN_VBOXDRV -DIPRT_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_PRESERVING -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS -DCONFIG_VBOXDRV_AS_MISC -DRT_ARCH_AMD64  -DMODULE  -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"SUPDrvGip"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"vboxdrv"' -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvGip.o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvGip.c
  gcc -Wp,-MMD,/tmp/vbox.0/.SUPDrvSem.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/include -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -fno-PIE -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Wno-format-security -Wno-address-of-packed-member -std=gnu89 -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -fno-jump-tables -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-frame-address -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-format-overflow -Wno-address-of-packed-member -O2 -fno-allow-store-data-races -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -fstack-protector -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wno-unused-const-variable -fno-var-tracking-assignments -g -pg -mrecord-mcount -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -flive-patching=inline-clone -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-stringop-truncation -Wno-zero-length-bounds -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-restrict -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -fno-strict-overflow -fno-merge-all-constants -fmerge-constants -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=designated-init -fmacro-prefix-map=./= -fcf-protection=none -Wno-packed-not-aligned -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-pie -Wno-declaration-after-statement -I./include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_WITHOUT_PRAGMA_ONCE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DSUPDRV_WITH_RELEASE_LOGGER -DVBOX_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_SET_IN_VBOXDRV -DIPRT_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_PRESERVING -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS -DCONFIG_VBOXDRV_AS_MISC -DRT_ARCH_AMD64  -DMODULE  -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"SUPDrvSem"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"vboxdrv"' -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvSem.o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvSem.c
   ./tools/objtool/objtool orc generate  --module --no-fp --retpoline --uaccess /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvSem.o
  gcc -Wp,-MMD,/tmp/vbox.0/.SUPDrvTracer.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/include -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -include ./include/linux/compiler_types.h -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Werror=strict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -fno-PIE -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=implicit-int -Wno-format-security -Wno-address-of-packed-member -std=gnu89 -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -fno-jump-tables -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-frame-address -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-format-overflow -Wno-address-of-packed-member -O2 -fno-allow-store-data-races -Wframe-larger-than=2048 -fstack-protector -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wno-unused-const-variable -fno-var-tracking-assignments -g -pg -mrecord-mcount -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -flive-patching=inline-clone -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wvla -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-stringop-truncation -Wno-zero-length-bounds -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-restrict -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -fno-strict-overflow -fno-merge-all-constants -fmerge-constants -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=designated-init -fmacro-prefix-map=./= -fcf-protection=none -Wno-packed-not-aligned -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-pie -Wno-declaration-after-statement -I./include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_WITHOUT_PRAGMA_ONCE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DSUPDRV_WITH_RELEASE_LOGGER -DVBOX_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_SET_IN_VBOXDRV -DIPRT_WITHOUT_EFLAGS_AC_PRESERVING -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS -DCONFIG_VBOXDRV_AS_MISC -DRT_ARCH_AMD64  -DMODULE  -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"SUPDrvTracer"' -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"vboxdrv"' -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvTracer.o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvTracer.c
In file included from ./include/asm-generic/percpu.h:7,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/percpu.h:556,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:78,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:51,
                 from /tmp/vbox.0/linux/../SUPDrvInternal.h:79,
                 from /tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:32:
/tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c: In function ‘supdrvOSChangeCR4’:
/tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:760:38: error: ‘cpu_tlbstate’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘cpuhp_state’?
  760 |     RTCCUINTREG uOld = this_cpu_read(cpu_tlbstate.cr4);
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:318:9: note: in definition of macro ‘__pcpu_size_call_return’
  318 |  typeof(variable) pscr_ret__;     \
      |         ^~~~~~~~
/tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:760:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘this_cpu_read’
  760 |     RTCCUINTREG uOld = this_cpu_read(cpu_tlbstate.cr4);
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:760:38: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
  760 |     RTCCUINTREG uOld = this_cpu_read(cpu_tlbstate.cr4);
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:318:9: note: in definition of macro ‘__pcpu_size_call_return’
  318 |  typeof(variable) pscr_ret__;     \
      |         ^~~~~~~~
/tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:760:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘this_cpu_read’
  760 |     RTCCUINTREG uOld = this_cpu_read(cpu_tlbstate.cr4);
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:281: /tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
   ./tools/objtool/objtool orc generate  --module --no-fp --retpoline --uaccess /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvTracer.o
/tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvTracer.o: warning: objtool: .text+0x7: indirect jump found in RETPOLINE build
/tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvTracer.o: warning: objtool: supdrvTracerProbeFireStub() is missing an ELF size annotation
   ./tools/objtool/objtool orc generate  --module --no-fp --retpoline --uaccess /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvGip.o
   ./tools/objtool/objtool orc generate  --module --no-fp --retpoline --uaccess /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrv.o
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1756: /tmp/vbox.0] Error 2
make: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/Makefile-footer.gmk:117: vboxdrv] Error 2
```

I am using Fedora 32.

Comment: You already figured out a solution, but the reason is quite simple: Your kernel was too new and the VirtualBox modules were not compatible.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with VirtualBox 6.0.22. Upgrading to VirtualBox 6.1.16 (https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) resolved the problem for me (Debian 10, kernel 5.8.0). Also saved guest session survived.

Don't forget to upgrade also VirtualBox Guest Additions to proper version, VirtualBox will offer download of this package when installing a new version, but you need to install VBox Guest Additions then from guest.

Answer (score 0):

The last update seems to fixed the issue

Comment: The last update to what? The kernel? VirtualBox?  Can you specify a version number that works? … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that newer kernels will often need an update from within `virtualbox` itself, in addition to a recompile. You *should* have the latest version if you have installed/configured the Virtualbox apt/yum repo. In any case, you should be able to download the latest version for your flavour of Linux from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads. This error should go away when you have the latest version of `virtualbox`, though potentially it might take a while for them to update if you have an RC or very recently released kernel.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I was using VBox 6.1.12.  I downloaded and installed VBox 6.1.14. Probably solved!

Comment: Do you mean “problem solved”? If you mean “probably solved”, then, please don’t post an answer until you’re reasonably sure that it works.